# Dúvidas sobre o tipo de dados sql

Tags: mysql

Qual o melhor tipo de dados sql devo usar para valores no caso de inclusão de notas dos produtos? As notas vão desde: 1.0, 1.5,... até 10.0. Estive pensando em usar o Double, mas não sei se seria o ideal. Para valores monetários uso o DECIMAL(10,2), mas não seria o caso. Estou usando o Mysql.

Comment: Conforme mostra aí depende se quer exatidão ou não. De forma geral eu só não uso o `decimal` se tiver um motivo muito forte.

Comment: Se for "nota" no sentido de pontuação e realmente quiser "escovar bits", e for de .5 em .5, pode usar um inteiro de 1 byte só, e dobrar a escala (fazer de 0 a 20, sendo que o valor real é metade - 1 = 0.5 ponto, 2 = 1 ponto, 5 = 2.5 pontos. etc) - resta saber se precisa mesmo disso. Ai ao armazenar, SET notadupla = nota * 2, e ao pegar SELECT notadupla / 2 AS nota (ainda assim, não sei se justifica no lugar do decimal)

Comment: Olá Bacco. Na verdade coloquei 1.0, 1.5 como exemplo, pois a nota será de 1.0 a 10.0, podendo ser 1.4, 2.7, etc.

Comment: @Fox.11 ou seja, a escala pode ser de 0 à 100.